# Submit email form to .txt file won't work

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have made a script with a form which is supposed to submit a persons email to a .txt file, only problem is that nothing happends to the .txt file, it is kept blank when the function is called. Both the html file and the php file is kept in the same folder and the .txt file is named formdata.txt .

Html code:

```
<form name="newsletter-form" action="process-form-data.php" method="post" id="newsletter-form">
            <input type="email" name="newsletter-email" id="newsletter-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" data-validate="validate(required, email)" />
            <input type="submit" id="newsletter-submit" class="btn" value="Notify Me" />
        </form>
```

Php code named process-form-data.php:

```
    <?php

// Receive form Post data and Saving it in variables
$email = $_POST['newsletter-email'];

// Write the name of text file where data will be store
$filename = "formdata.txt";

// Marge all the variables with text in a single variable. 
$f_data= '
Email :  '.$email.'
=========================
';

echo 'Form data has been saved to '.$filename.'  <br>
<a href="'.$filename.'">Click here to read </a> ';
$file = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($file,$f_data);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me.

Here's a variation using file_put_contents:

```
// Receive form Post data and Saving it in variables
$email = $_POST['newsletter-email'];
//$email = 'myhappymail@unhappy.com';

// Write the name of text file where data will be store
$filename = "formdata.txt";

// Marge all the variables with text in a single variable. 
$f_data= '
Email2! :  '.$email.'
=========================
';
file_put_contents( $filename, $f_data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );

// $file = fopen($filename, "a");
// fwrite($file,$f_data);
// fclose($file);
echo 'Form data has been saved to '.$filename.'  <br>
<a href="'.$filename.'">Click here to read </a> ';
```

Do a:

```
var_dump( $_POST );
die;
```

at the top of your script. I'm thinking you're missing your POST data.

Comment: If that were the issue, then at least the decoration stuff should get added to the file...

Comment: Thank you, but I have just tested your edit and the .txt file is still kept blank

Comment: Might be a permissions issue. Remove the file and run this to see if you can write to it. file_put_contents( 'formdata.txt', 'great test!', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX ); If it does not re-create the file and add the data consider changing your write directory permissions to 755 or on windows running xamp/wamp as administrator.